# According to top, my node.js application is using 100% of my CPU

Tags: node.js

The application is actually open-source: http://www.github.com/zackster/CompassionPit-Node--

What are the high-level steps to profiling my application to see where it's soaking up CPU resources?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and attention to read my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector) to profile your code. That will show where it's spending most of its time.